# Swift 2 - NSJONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData with guard statement "Cannot convert value of type Element..."

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I've started a Swift 2 project and I'm attempting to wrap my head around `do`, `guard` and `throws`.  There are several other questions on Stack concerning this, but the issue I'm having is slightly different.

Here is my code:

```
enum JSONParsingError: String, ErrorType {
    case URLCreationFailed = "Error: URL creation failed"
    case SerializationFailed = "Error: JSON Parsing failed"
    case DataDownloadingFailed = "Error: downloading data failed"
    case DictionaryError = "Error: dictionary creation from JSON failed."
}

 func fetchUserRepositories(urlString: String) throws {
        do {
            guard let reposURL = NSURL(string: urlString) else { throw JSONParsingError.URLCreationFailed }

        guard let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: reposURL) else { throw JSONParsingError.DataDownloadingFailed }

        guard let jsonDictionary: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary else { throw JSONParsingError.SerializationFailed }

        guard let reposArray = jsonDictionary["repos"] as? NSDictionary else { throw JSONParsingError.DictionaryError }

        for repo in reposArray {
            repositories.append(TestRepo(json: repo))
        }
    }
}
```

Regardless of how I cast `jsonDictionary["repos"]` I keep getting the same error in my for loop:

`Cannot convert value of type 'Element' (aka '(key: AnyObject, value: AnyObject)') to expected argument type 'NSDictionary'` (TestRepo is just a simple class that is initialized with a dictionary.  Not the most ideal way, I know).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reposArray` is a dictionary, that is a collection of couples `(key, value)`. In your code:

```
for repo in reposArray {
        repositories.append(TestRepo(json: repo))
    }
```

`repo` is bound to each element in turn.  So, if `TestRepo` expects as parameter a dictionary, it receives instead an element (a couple `(key, value)`), and this is the cause of the error.

Comment: Wow, thank you.  I was so caught up in focusing on `guard` that I completely missed that.